# Scenario : Sql query to populate populate Y or N

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in building SQL query to populate Y or N for the below scenario :
There are two tables and I need to compare the data of field 1 in table 1 with field 1 in table 2 and populate Y or N :

Table 1:

```
Field 1
Y
N
```

**Table 2:**

```
Field 2
Y
N
YES
No
NULL
Yes
```

So as per above scenario if field 1 is 'Y' ,Field 2 is also 'Y' then populate 'Y'.

- If field 1 is Y and field 2 is N populate 'Y'
- if field 1 is N and field 2 is Y populate 'Y'
- if field 1 is N and field 2 is Yes populate 'Y'

so basically if any of the field contain Y,Yes,YES then populate 'Y' else populate N

I am trying to build this logic based on case statement but not sure if this is the correct way.

```
case when field 1 ='Y' or field 2='Y' then 'Y' 
when field 1='Y' or field 2='YES' then 'Y'
```

Comment: Hi,Apologies...updated the naming convention in table 2

Comment: how are the tables joined, cross join?

Comment: @nbk-Its left join on table 1

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: `case when 'Y' in(substr(field1, 1, 1), substr(field2, 1, 1)) then 'Y' else 'N' end` or `greatest(field1, substr(coalesce(field2, 'N'), 1,1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below simplified CASE statement

```
CASE WHEN field_1='N' AND NVL(field_2,'N') IN ('N','No')
THEN 'N'
ELSE
'Y'
END
```